# Javascript - JQuery - Kendo - Why is my function executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

Hi I'm kinda new to JS and I'm trying to figure out why i'm getting unexpected behavior.
I'm trying to define some functions and hook up some buttons but some events are firing on page load and I can't tell what determines if it will fire or not and more importantly how to stop it.

```
//this one does not execute on page load
var saveDataCallback = function(){
    alert('Save Successful');
};

//this one executes on page load        
var addFieldToForm = function(){
    alert('wtf mate');
};


$(document).ready(function(){
    //this one does not execute the alert when I load the page
    $("#showMePOTATOSALAD").on('click', function (){ alert(JSON.stringify(formDataObj)) });

    var dialog = $("#addToFormDialog");
    //this one does execute the dialog open when I load the page           
    $("#addToForm").on('click', function(){ dialog.data("kendoDialog").open() });
}
```

this was the issue

```
dialog.kendoDialog({
    title:'Add Field to Form',
    modal:true,
    width: 500,
    height: 350,
    content:"",
    actions:[
        {text: 'Cancel'},
        {text: 'Add', action: addFieldToForm() }
    ]   
});
```

Changed to

```
dialog.kendoDialog({
    title:'Add Field to Form',
    modal:true,
    width: 500,
    height: 350,
    **visible: false,**
    content:"",
    actions:[
        {text: 'Cancel'},
        {text: 'Add', action: **addFieldToForm** }
    ]   
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there any other javascript on the page? I'd guess there must be something else that is triggering these

Comment: As you have posted, NOTHING should fire; you are missing a close paren. Also, please post all relevant code/fragments... as @icecream mentioned, must be interference from other JS (if not on that page, maybe in your include?)

Comment: There is a lot of JS on the page. There is however nowhere else on the page that references those variables or elements. I have confirmed that the addFieldToForm is executing before page load with breakpoints.

Comment: I got it. It was the dialog options. I had to specify visible:false and I had the callback assignment wrong. i put parenthesis addFieldToForm(), instead of just the name addFieldToForm

Comment: @Rushikumar post your parentheses comment as an answer and i'll mark it as answer. You were right the issue was with parentheses.

Comment: @KennyLucero there you go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, your `document ready` code block is missing a close parenthesis...

Change the following--

```
    $("#addToForm").on('click', function(){ dialog.data("kendoDialog").open() });
}
```

To:

```
    $("#addToForm").on('click', function(){ dialog.data("kendoDialog").open() });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //this one does not execute the alert when I load the page
    $("#showMePOTATOSALAD").on('click', function (){ alert(JSON.stringify(formDataObj)) });

    var dialog = $("#addToFormDialog");
    //this one does execute the dialog open when I load the page           
    $("#addToForm").on('click', function(){ dialog.data("kendoDialog").open() });
}
```

it's normal, the alert will be displayed when YOU CLICK ON THE ELEMENT WITH THE ID=showMePOTATOSALAD and the dialog when YOU CLICK on THE ELEMENT WITH THE ID=addToForm.

Comment: that was the expected behavior. the issue was that the click open method call was being execute on loading the page in addition to the click event.